# Draw circle in Android without aliasing

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on Android project, and I'm using View class to drawing empty circle on canvas.
This is my code:

```
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true); // enable anti aliasing
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); // set default color to light green
    paint.setDither(true); // enable dithering
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // set to STOKE
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); // set the join to round you want
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  // set the paint cap to round too
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 50, paint);
```

But the result circle has some aliasing, how can I draw circle without any aliasing?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the below shown code for drawing circle in a canvas :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_Image);
        createBitMap();
    }

    private void createBitMap() {
        Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // creates
                                                                                // bmp
        bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true); // lets bmp to be
                                                        // mutable
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap); // draw a canvas in defined bmp

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        // smooths
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
        // opacity
        // p.setAlpha(0x80); //
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Paint antialiasing flag:

```
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG

If this doesn't work, the circle is probably aready antialiased, but your screen density is too low to notice.

Comment: I'm used paint.setAntiAlias(true); and then used your code paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG), it is same same, has some aliasing.

Comment: I hope I understand (check image): your result looks like one on the LEFT and you want it to look like one on the RIGHT? Or is it the other way around?  http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/9/90921/2438801-0787557059-Anti-.jpg